# Is it possible to display large text on an NXT using LabVIEW?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, programming, labview

In RoboLab and [using RobotC](http://www.robotc.net/support/nxt/MindstormsWebHelp/index.htm#page=nxt_functions/display/Display.htm), it's possible to write LARGE text to the screen of the NXT. In RoboLab, this can be done by just typing `[\big]` at the beginning of a string constant which is wired into a display VI. For some reason, this doesn't seem to work when programming with LabVIEW, and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. It appears that the larger font is built-in to the NXT's firmware, so there should be *some* way to achieve this. How can I display large text on the NXT's screen using LabVIEW?

Answer (score 3):

I am not used to LabVIEW... but RIC image files, supported by NXT firmware, can also be used by LabView I guess. So [nxtRICEdit](http://ric.dreier-privat.de/Docu/index_eng.htm) may help. See also [RICfont utility](https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/mindboards/download/file.php?id=90), more information (though targetted NXC/NXT-G, should be useful) [here](https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/mindboards/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=135#p1210).

Comment: Hm. I'll have to look into this more. I need to be able to display dynamic text (e.g. results of data acquisition) on the screen, so there would need to be a way to generate RIC images dynamically.

Comment: RIC files can take parameters and display accordingly. RIC fonts are based on this idea, they take the character to draw as the first parameter, which then causes them to display the proper character.
The extended NXT firmware has a special function which uses such a file to automatically display all characters. You can do it yourself pretty easily if all characters are the same width though.
I'm the author of RICcreator, a slightly more modern alternative to nxtRICEdit

Comment: I'm the author of RICcreator, a slightly more modern alternative to nxtRICEdit, so I should be able to answer about anything about the RIC format if you need help. (constantly hitting enter ruined this comment... -__-)